# Fit Angular Material Grid into view height

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular app where I have each component set viewheight as 100%

```html
<div class="container">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-bio></app-bio>
    <app-home></app-home> <!-- just a coloring/layout purpose -->
</div>
```

In global style(`styles.css`), I set section to having viewheight 100% so that each component takes up the entire screen
**styles.css**

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
}

body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**app-home**

```html
<section class="home-container">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
</section>
```

```css
.home-container {
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

`app-bio` works as expected, which takes up the entire screen and its color is skyblue
[image]

I would like an Angular Material grid to display my content in `<app-bio>` tag but the grids are off the its component and takes up some space of the next angular component(which is the **next** `<app-home>`

[image]

**app-bio**

```html
<section class="bio-wrapper">
    <mat-grid-list [cols]="2">
        <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
</section>
```

```css
.bio-wrapper {
    background: silver;
}
```

Did I do wrong in css? Is there a way to fit the grid in height of parent tag?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to layout content so that the child "stretches" to the height and/or width of it's parent.

Personally in angular I would recommend the use of FlexLayout: -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout

Examples: -
https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Once you get over the initial learning curve of using this library all kinds of options for easy and responsive layout are open to you.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" id="parent">
  <div fxFlex="100" id="child">Content Here</div>
</div>
```